# How do I use a for each loop to count the number of occurences in an array based on a given callback using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, count, callback

I need help in creating a count function that returns the number of elements for which callback is true.

For example, if the array and callback were as follows:
count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3);
The expected answer would be 1.

Or if the array and callback were as follows:
count([], (e) => e === 'd');
The expected outcome would be 0.

How do I create this count function? It must use a for each loop.

Comment: let count=0;

[1,2,3,4].forEach(x=>x==3?count++:null)

Comment: Please show us your attempt at solving this exercise. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a count that you increment each time the predicate returns true.

```js
function count(arr, pred){
  let count = 0;
  arr.forEach(x => {
    if(pred(x)) ++count;
  });
  return count;
}
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3));
```

`Array#reduce` could also be used for this, making use of the fact that `true` can be coerced to `1` and `false` to `0`.

```js
function count(arr, pred){
  return arr.reduce((sum, x) => sum + !!pred(x), 0);
}
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3));
```

Comment: I'd recommend `sum + !!pred(x)` just to make sure it's a boolean that's counted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to synchronous callbacks (as in your examples), then built in `[].filter` essentially does this for you.

```js
let count = (array, predicate) => array.filter(predicate).length;

console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1], (e) => e >= 3));
```